# Parts of my (apparently manifold) model aren't appearing in my Slic3r preview

Tags: slicing, slic3r

I have an STL file that, when I load it in Slic3r, looks fine, but somewhere in the actual slicing process, something goes wrong and parts of the model disappear.

[image: Render and slicing preview]

That's the render on the left, and the slicing preview on the right. That big hole is the most obvious fault, but there are more little notches elsewhere on the model; you can see a couple on the bottom edge there. It looks like the program is ignoring some of the model's faces entirely. What's all that about?

The model passes every manifoldiness test I've thrown at it: Slic3r's, Meshmixer's, Blender's, and a couple of online services I've forgotten.The walls that go missing are pretty thin, but they're at least a millimeter at their narrowest point, so I think it should be thick enough for the printer to handle.

Here's a link to the STL file in question, on FileHosting.org, [FlashHovering.stl](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/664957/FlashHovering.stl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it!

I had my extruder diameter set to 0.5 mm, and the narrowest point of the model was just a hair under a full millimeter, so I guess the program took it to mean that it should only put down one line of material. I made the walls a little thicker and now it looks fine.

Comment: You should modify your original question or post your new question separately.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to the original question, in order to remove it from the [Unanswered questions](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list - which, as we are a Beta site, we need to keep as small as possible if we are to graduate to being a full site. Also, your additional question, should be asked as a separate question. You can always link back to this question, in your new question, in order to provide more context.

Comment: Done. I got rid of the extra question - it seemed like it was a little too speculative to merit its own entry.